# Ionic check internet connection with Cordova

Tags: cordova, networking, ionic-framework

Is there a problem with version of Cordova network information plugin I'm using (1.2.1)? I can't seem to get it to work in any way. I have followed the sample code in documentation and it doesn't work.

I've tried putting it to a separate factory, directly in view and in controller.

I've tried reinstalling the plugin and repeating the process.

Usually I was getting an error that the 'type' is not defined, and then I tried to put the function to trigger on device ready. It didn't help.

If I get to the point where I don't get the 'type' error, I am getting back that the connection is undefined.

Each step was followed by installing on a device and in browser also.

I have tried copy/pasting different tutorial solutions, and other people solutions, it also didn't work.

I can paste the code here, but it has been altered for about 100 times since I'm stuck on this for 4 hours and counting...so if there is some helpful information you can provide, I'd be grateful.

**EDIT** - latest code:

```
checkInternetConnection: function(){

                    alert('Function triggered'); // triggered

                    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

                    function onDeviceReady() {
                        alert('I am ready!'); // not triggered
                        checkConnection();
                    }

                    function checkConnection() {
                        var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

                        var states = {};
                        states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
                        states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
                        states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
                        states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
                        states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
                        states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
                        states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
                        states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

                        alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
                    }
                }
```

First alert is called, so function is triggered, second one not. Apparently device is not ready (this goes both for browser and device)

Comment: Unfortunately without code it will be difficult to help out. Check out this simple sample - https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/06/check-network-connection-with-ionicframework/

Comment: Your deviceready event is not invoked and that means you have not included cordova.js file in your html. This is the script which ensures deviceready event is fired

Comment: Well it actually is included in the main index.html. Even if I put the script right below the included cordova.js, it doesn't get triggered

Comment: deviceready event should be registered on page onload. Check out this link - https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova/events/events.deviceready.html

Comment: I tried that now, still nothing =/ I did do a system restore few days ago, so maybe something is missing? I updated nodejs now, reinstalled plugin and updated android platform...any more ideas? My ionic -v is 1.3.1

Comment: try running a barebone Cordova project with device plugin and see if its working in that case